How to calculate the p-value of a two-tailed alternative hypothesis test using python?
I thought that the two methods below would give the same result as they are equivalent, theoretically. However, they differ slightly in Python!
from scipy.stats import norm

# let's assume that our z-statistic = 3
z_score = 3

# method 1:
print(2 * min(norm.cdf(z_score), 1-norm.cdf(z_score)))    # outputs: 0.002699796063260207

# method 2:
print(norm.cdf(-abs(z_score)) + 1-norm.cdf(abs(z_score))) # outputs: 0.002699796063260096

# Notice that they differ in the last 3 digits!

My thought is that the default values for loc and scale in norm.cdf are 0 and 1, respectively. So, this function generates a standard normal distribution with symmetric tails as it's not a skewed distribution. As a result, when I multiply the area under one tail by two, it should be the same as summing areas under the left and right tails. So, why is there a difference?

To be fair, they agree to 13 significant digits.

You're correct. Theoretically, both methods should give the same result for calculating the p-value of a z-score in a standard normal distribution. I beleive that the small difference you're observing are due to the precision limits and floating-point arithmetic used by the norm.cdf function in Python.
Python, like most programming languages, follows IEEE 754 standards for floating-point arithmetic. These floating-point numbers can't always represent decimals exactly, so each mathematical operation might introduce minuscule differences depending on the order of operations and how the numbers are represented internally.
While these differences are tiny (in the order of 10^(−14)), they can still appear at the level of precision you're working with. This explains why you see a discrepancy in the last few decimal places even though both methods are theoretically equivalent.
In summary:
The two methods call the same function (norm.cdf), but the order of operations and intermediate calculations lead to slightly different floating-point approximations.
